# inAppBrowser cannot display but work fine in chrome

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

It is work fine in mobile chrome but cannot display in inAppBrowser.
I want to know that why they have different.
Did I need to add the javascript ti index.html?

Comment: What you want to display. Describe your question properly.

Comment: I want to display "fullcalendar", It work on IPhone, ipad and Samsung s8, but cannot work on LG v20 and xiaomi.

Comment: Please expand your question to be more clear, and include the source code of the method you are using to invoke to inAppBrowser. We can't help you if you don't provide more details, we are not in front of your screen.